# Start serial read when the data begins with empty string

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I'm having a problem reading serial data from Arduino to Python. I'm sending some comma separated data from sensors with one Serial.println function and from Arduino side, everything seems to be fine. On the other side, in Python I should format that data to float and int, but first line is always empty and I get error when converting it to float.

```
b = ser.readline()
string_n = b.decode()
string = string_n.rstrip()
sensor = string.split(',')
senzor1 = list(filter(None, sensor))
print(sensor1)
```

I tried with this option, to filter empty string but I got this as result:

```
[]
['-9.84', ' 27']
['-5.14', ' 29']
['-13.83', ' 25']
['0.82', ' 31']
```

Otherwise, first line is [' '] and the it starts with sensor readings.

So, only have one Serial.println on my Arduino side. Any idea how to remove this empty list or how to improve it?

Comment: I'm thinking that you could create an array that is pre-populated with zeros, and only then add your values?  Alternatively can you just delete the first list it kicks out?

Comment: What't the content of b exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid creating the list from inside the list.

You can either do:

```
b = ser.readline()
string_n = b.decode().strip()
sensor1 = [x.strip() for x in string_n.split(',') if x.strip()]
if sensor1:
    print(sensor1)
```

or:

```
b = ser.readline()
string_n = b.decode().strip()
if ',' in string_n:
    sensor1 = [x.strip() for x in string_n.split(',') if x.strip()]
    print(sensor1)
```

Comment: Still the same, first print is just [ ]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to Serial.print zeros on Arduino as initial state, before sensors start with work, that way it Python will read zeros at beginning instead of empty space and it's not affecting later work. Thanks for help Tom.